# How to debug dysfunctional internet access on mobile data?

Tags: mobile-data, android-10, debug

On a new **Shift 6mq** with **Android 10** (light version without Google services) apps **don't have internet access via mobile data**. Unfortunately I usually use WiFi so I didn't notice when internet vi mobile data stopped working.
Since I've fiddled with the system a bit (unlocked bootloader, installed Magisk + some plugins) maybe the best would be to first reset everything and start from a working system but I'm curious how to find the broken link, so maybe you give me some hint's how to narrow down the problem generically.

Here is what I'm observing and what I already tried:

- Apps don't have internet access via mobile data but they do via WiFi
- I cleaned the sim card and tried it on another phone
- therefore I rebooted the phone
- mobile network is activated, airplane mode deactivated
- in system settings mobile data seems to be working, carrier is shown, no problems reported
- data saver is disabled
- Data usage is *0 bytes* which looks like even system layer has no access
- Magisk, AFWall+, XPosed deinstalled
- Check your APN settings - maybe you have to transfer them from a working phone

Now, are there any further things I can check to find the root cause? Maybe via `adb shell`?

Comment: Are you sure AFWall+ is not blocking it? Start with `ping` and `dig`. Then check network routing with `ip rule` and `ip route`. Use `iptables` to check firewall blocking.

Comment: I even deinstalled it, but it's not been AFWall but a wrong APN entry. Was a bug in latest firmware..